# How to make sure that a GPU is damaged?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, hardware-failure, crash, gpu

a few days ago my computer shut down due overheating. At that moment I was building an android game, but the pressure on my computer wasn't as much as it could handle until some weeks ago.

I turned it on again but the problem continued and it kept overheating and shutting down.

I thought it's my CPU(FX 8350) that's getting hot, I cleaned all the dust from my CPU fan (deepcool lucifer v2) and assembled it again. but same thing happened agian.

I downloaded a software (Corsair Link) to check the temperature of the parts and I found that it's the motherboard (m5a99fx pro r2.0) that is getting too hot.

I googled my problem and found an answer which was pointing to some kind of software issues that might cause a pc to overheat.

Then I decided to reinstall my windows (win 10).

It took like 17 hours for me to reinstall the windows and it kept crashing and throwing `(the installation failed in the safe_os phase with an error during apply_image operation)` error. which seems to be a problem related to graphic card.

finally I managed to install the windows. but the problem continued. I was kind of sure that, either the mother board is damaged, or a part is drawing too much power that causes the motherboard to overheat.

My graphic card is NVidia GTX 750Ti zotac, it doesn't require a six pin power socket. it gets it's power directly from the mother board. in other words, no cable from the power supply goes into the GPU.

I changed the graphic card to another GPU slot and it suddenly fixed the problem. I Decompressed a 20GB file which would instantly crash my computer before changing my graphic slot and ran a game at max setting and it was fine. (my monitor is 768p, 750Ti performs relatively good on this resolution).

my motherboard hit 54°
gpu hit 70°
cpu hit 42°

but today morning, the computer kept crashing again at 2-5% load and the VGA_LED on my motherboard turned on. I restarted and crashing kept happening again and again. and once, the monitor went off but the case was still on.

I feel like my graphic card is damaged but I'm not sure, I went to a PC center near my home(I live in asia) but people in the PC center were really unprofessional. So I decided to ask in here for some help.

Can you please help me diagnose whether it is the GPU that is damaged or it's the motherboard?

Best regards.

Comment: Your motherboard overheating wouldn’t cause Windows to take 17 hours to install.  What it actually sounds like is a failed mechanical HDD

Comment: @Ramhound Maybe i didn't explain it the best way. the windows took 17 hours to take because it kept crashing and crashing 
it were throwing (`the installation failed in the safe_os phase with an error during apply_image operation`) which it seems is related to graphic card. according to windowsreport.com

Comment: It’s extremely difficult to overheat a motherboard

Comment: @Ramhound well, i don't know. i'm not doing it on purpose. I think a part (i think gpu) is drawing too much power. and in that case, i think it's a sign that tell ms the gpu is damaged. but i'm not professional in that area

Comment: How to make sure your GPU is damaged? How to make sure your friend is dead while on the phone to 911? BANG!

Answer (score 1):

If you suspect your GPU is bad, the only way to be sure is to swap it out
with another graphical card.

For general testing of the hardware, a good all-around test is
[MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/).
Run it for as long as is possible for you, but at a minimum for 2 passes.